# How to pass a custom script to ./configure to be run after the compiling?

Tags: ios, makefile, clang, configure

I'm trying to build the Tor project in my jailbroken iOS device. I cloned the Git repository, and ran autogen.sh. Next, I ran ./configure, and a C compiler was not found. So I ran this instead (after installing Clang, Theos Dependencies, etc. from the repos):

```
./configure CC="clang --isysroot /var/mobile/theos/sdks/iPhoneOS11.2.sdk"
```

Now it says that it can't run the C compiled program:

```
PoisonImy:~/tor mobile$ ./configure CC="clang -isysroot /var/mobile/theos/sdks/iPhoneOS11.2.sdk"
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /bin/mkdir -p
checking for gawk... no
checking for mawk... no
checking for nawk... no
checking for awk... no
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking whether make supports nested variables... yes
checking whether make supports nested variables... (cached) yes
checking whether make supports the include directive... yes (GNU style)
checking for gcc... clang -isysroot /var/mobile/theos/sdks/iPhoneOS11.2.sdk
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables...
checking whether we are cross compiling... configure: error: in `/var/mobile/tor':               
configure: error: cannot run C compiled programs.
If you meant to cross compile, use `--host'.
See `config.log' for more details
```

This is because of the "Killed: 9" error I got earlier when I compiled a hello world program using Clang and attempted to run it. I fixed it by using 'ldid -SEntitlements.plist a.out', with the Entitlements.plist file in [here](https://pastebin.com/Kn1SqmBj).

Is there any way to instruct the configure script (or clang) to do the same?

EDIT: Maybe making a shell script that runs clang and ldid, and then passing that to the configure script? I'll try this one. I'm new to shell scripting so I have no idea how to approach this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Done. Here's the script I used:

```
#!/bin/bash

ALL="$*"

while [[ $# -gt 0 ]]
do
key="$1"

case $key in
    -o)
    OUTPUT="$2"
    shift
    shift
    ;;
    *)
    shift
    ;;
esac
done

clang -isysroot /var/mobile/theos/sdks/iPhoneOS11.2.sdk ${ALL}
ldid -S/var/mobile/Entitlements.plist ${OUTPUT}
```

I saved it as 'compiler.sh', made it executable, and put it in my PATH. And then I used that for my compiler in the configure script. You may need to adjust the SDK directory and Entitlements.plist directory on your own.